# xcode 6 pch.file not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I load my project from xcode 5 to xcode 6 and see error myProject-prefix.pch is not found in myProjectTests, I add this file and see new error

```
Ld /Users/willrock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Мобильный_Extreme_Fitness-cdfxpafcwvsczkfjvlwznradvmhm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Мобильный\ Extreme\ FitnessTests.xctest/Мобильный\ Extreme\ FitnessTests normal x86_64
cd /Users/willrock/Desktop/ExtremeFitness
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -L/Users/willrock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Мобильный_Extreme_Fitness-cdfxpafcwvsczkfjvlwznradvmhm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/willrock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Мобильный_Extreme_Fitness-cdfxpafcwvsczkfjvlwznradvmhm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/willrock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Мобильный_Extreme_Fitness-cdfxpafcwvsczkfjvlwznradvmhm/Build/Intermediates/Мобильный\ Extreme\ Fitness.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Мобильный\ Extreme\ FitnessTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Мобильный\ Extreme\ FitnessTests.LinkFileList -bundle_loader /Users/willrock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Мобильный_Extreme_Fitness-cdfxpafcwvsczkfjvlwznradvmhm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/extreme_fitness.app/extreme_fitness -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework XCTest -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework XCTest -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/willrock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Мобильный_Extreme_Fitness-cdfxpafcwvsczkfjvlwznradvmhm/Build/Intermediates/Мобильный\ Extreme\ Fitness.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Мобильный\ Extreme\ FitnessTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Мобильный\ Extreme\ FitnessTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/willrock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Мобильный_Extreme_Fitness-cdfxpafcwvsczkfjvlwznradvmhm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Мобильный\ Extreme\ FitnessTests.xctest/Мобильный\ Extreme\ FitnessTests
```

l`d: file not found: /Users/willrock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Мобильный_Extreme_Fitness-cdfxpafcwvsczkfjvlwznradvmhm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/extreme_fitness.app/extreme_fitness
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

if i load project see in xctest

`clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/willrock/Desktop/ExtremeFitness/extreme_fitness/extreme_fitness-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1`

but in xcode 5 is work fine

Comment: clean project. Remove derrived data floder of your app from organizer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

i solved it - in targets delete xctest target and it compiled

Comment: It's a sham workaround, because don't solve problem, but remove it from radix! If I want to add back test target?

Answer (score 107):

1. Make new file: <kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
2. iOS/Mac > Other > PCH File > YourProject-Prefix.pch.
3. Make sure you display "All" and not "Basic". (Blue buttons)
4. Project > Build Settings > Search: "Prefix Header".
5. Under "Apple LLVM 7.0" you will get the *Prefix Header* key.
6. Type file directory. e.g: "$(SRCROOT)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/ProjectName-Prefix.pch".
7. Clean project: <kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⇧shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
8. Build project: <kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

---

[image: Prefix Header Image]

Comment: On step 5 I'd type `$(SRCROOT)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/YourProject-Prefix.pch` instead.

Comment: There is no need "YourProjectName/YourProject-Prefix.pch".  you can directly specified .pch name

Comment: Errrr... It OBVIOUSLY depends where the file is.. No normal person keeps files outside the project folder.

Comment: after creating a a new pch file i have a new error . . . 
Linker command failed with exit code 1
ld: file not found: /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ABC-dnblevzgtsdkywcsetmlxmpcaada/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ABC_4.0.app/ABC_4.0 

any ideas or help ?

Comment: Delete the application from the device or simulator, then do Step 6 & 7. Let us know..

Comment: the app never got installed on the simulator . . . .

Comment: Oh well, open a new question, no one sees your question here. :)

Comment: thanks you for the advice and I just did -> here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576447/xcode-6-how-to-solve-precompile-prefix-header-error

Comment: This solution worked for me, I searched the item and added the project name / prefix name. I tried the prefix filename alone but didn't work.

Comment: Oh, In Xcode 7, just do it in the target and don't set Precomepile.

Answer (score 6):

Try this with Xcode 6. You need to manually create the PCH File.

File -> New -> File -> iOS -> C and C++ -> PCH File.

Add new PCH file to the project - New file > Other > PCH file

At the project 'Build Settings' option - set the value of 'Prefix Header' to your PCH file name, with the project name as prefix - i.e. for project named 'TestProject' and PCH file named 'MyPrefixHeaderFile', add the value 'TestProject/MyPrefixHeaderFile.pch' to the plist.

Comment: The lack of the PCH file is why my Xcode is whining all the time not recognizing UIKit and Foundation APIs on several classes. Man, these guys behind Xcode at Apple should be all fired for shipping a stuff so crappy like that. Every Xcode update it gets worse. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @spacedog Nothing says "I'm a rational, professional adult" like whining about your tools.

Comment: If you accept the crap without complaining things will not improve. Professionals always complain because they want to build better things and for that they need better tools. One cannot construct a gothic cathedral with a spoon and a fork.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of reasons for this issue and I had my own hits.I had to do two steps for my project to run.May be it can be helpful for others.

1. I deleted the entry in the **Prefix header** of Build Settings.

Path->  `Target> Build Settings > Prefix Header.`

2. Deleted the **Your Project Tests file** in the Targets.

   [screen shot for the second point](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9s6nycb58x3nzs/target_tests.png?dl=0).

Reference: http://www.buzztouch.com/forum/thread.php?tid=F42D8239A330C321132944A&currentPage=3

Answer (score 2):

Generate a new pch file.
Name the file as Demo-Prefix.Pch
Go to targets - Build Settings[image: like the screenshot problem solved exactly]

Comment: you could name the file whatever you want it doesn't need to be something specific, that being said i don't understand the down vote

Answer (score 1):

Do as follows, changing  [Precompile Prefix Header] with [no] 
and [Prefix Header] with empty field.

### And I rebuild the project, it passes, and runs!

```
[Project]
-[Basic]
-[Apple LLVM6.1-Language]
--[Precompile Prefix Header]-[no]
--[Prefix Header]--[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a description what you should do

1. Click on the first folder under the blue page with the project name. The folder with also have the project name next to it.
2. `File > New File > iOS > Other`
3. Click on `PCH File`
4. Click `Next`
5. Save As: `PrefixHeader`
6. Click the first checkbox under `Targets` **ONLY**; if others are checked, uncheck them
7. Click `Create`
8. If the `Prefix Header`" file ended up in a different folder, such as the `Supporting Files` folder, move it up to the top folder you clicked on in step 1
9. Click on the blue page at the top of the left sidebar with the project name next tot it. This is just above the folder you clicked on in step 1
10. Click on the `Build Settings` tab
11. In the search bar, type in, `Prefix Header` and press the `Return/Enter` key
12. Look for `Apple LLVM 6.0 or 7.0 - Language.` 6.0 refers to Xcode 6 and 7.0 refers to Xcode 7. This makes no difference.
13. Make sure `Increase Sharing of Precompiled Headers` is set to `No` and that `Precompile Prefix Header` is set to `No`
14. Find the `Prefix Header` line just under the `Precompile Prefix Header` Line. Move the cursor over about 5 inches, but stay on the same line. Double-Click. A box will open.
15. Type in the name of your project (this is stated next to the folder you clicked on in step 1)

    Example) Prereq for Overdue Assignment
     **It is VERY IMPORTANT that you type in capitals where needed such as "P" in "Prereq." It is case sensitive.** Now, put in  forward slash (`/`). Then type in the name of the file you created in steps 2-7 (**Again, this is Case Sensitive and you must put spaces where needed**). I recommend that you leave the file as `PrefixHeader` (no spaces). After the filename, such as `PrefixHeader`, type in `.pch`   **ALL lower case.**
16. The final result should look something like this:

    `Prereq for Overdue Assignment/PrefixHeader.pch`
17. Now, click on the `Product` menu (6 menus over from the file menu you clicked on in step 2). Then click on `Clean`

    **You can bypass this step by holding <kbd>command</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>, and <kbd>K</kbd> at the same time.**
     Once you get the message, `Clean Succeeded,` move on to step 18.
18. Click on the `Product` menu and go down to `Build`. Click on `Build`.

    **You can bypass this step by holding `command` and `B` at the same time.** You should get `Build Completed.`

Thats it!

Answer (score 0):

- select your framework in the file navigator
- open the utilities pane (Xcode -> View -> Utilities -> Show File Inspector)
- enable target membership of your framework for all targets.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your scheme name to what ever  you want.Clear the project then compile it.
Its working for me .