# Xcode File not found while trying to run app

Tags: xcode, file, testing

I'm Getting this error in Xcode then I try to run my app

```
Ld /Users/danielsorensen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Keyboard-cimemloksqjdnxhkdziqxwhxgwcg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/KeyboardTests.xctest/KeyboardTests normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/danielsorensen/Downloads/codecanyon-9105493-color-keyboard-universal/Color Custom Keyboard"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -L/Users/danielsorensen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Keyboard-cimemloksqjdnxhkdziqxwhxgwcg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/danielsorensen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Keyboard-cimemloksqjdnxhkdziqxwhxgwcg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/danielsorensen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Keyboard-cimemloksqjdnxhkdziqxwhxgwcg/Build/Intermediates/Keyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/KeyboardTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/KeyboardTests.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -bundle_loader /Users/danielsorensen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Keyboard-cimemloksqjdnxhkdziqxwhxgwcg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Color\ Custom\ Keyboard.app/Color\ Custom\ Keyboard -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework XCTest -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/danielsorensen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Keyboard-cimemloksqjdnxhkdziqxwhxgwcg/Build/Intermediates/Keyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/KeyboardTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/KeyboardTests.swiftmodule -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/danielsorensen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Keyboard-cimemloksqjdnxhkdziqxwhxgwcg/Build/Intermediates/Keyboard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/KeyboardTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/KeyboardTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/danielsorensen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Keyboard-cimemloksqjdnxhkdziqxwhxgwcg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/KeyboardTests.xctest/KeyboardTests

ld: file not found: /Users/danielsorensen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Keyboard-cimemloksqjdnxhkdziqxwhxgwcg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Color Custom Keyboard.app/Color Custom Keyboard
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: try the following solution: [xcode-6-pch-file-not-found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840720/xcode-6-pch-file-not-found)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I got the same error and I solved it by following these steps:

1) Go to the project

2) On the left side bar (in the screen that appears click on Tests

3) Go to the build settings tab and look for "test host"

4) Now the path that appears in the field is probably wrong so you just need to update it to the appropriate one (In my particular case I renamed the project and some folders and so some paths were wrong)
[image]

If you still see the error then you might need to fix some other paths in the Build settings tabs.

Comment: Huge help, thanks. Mine was set to `$(BUNDLE_LOADER)`, so I changed the Bundle Loader settings instead (in the Linking section). It was indeed caused by the app name having changed since the time the Tests target was created.

Comment: It's amazing! Thank you!

Comment: i have blank. can i have to add ?

Answer (score 8):

Go to `Project -- > Build Settings --> Testing --> Test Host` 
Remove the paths from Debug and Release and give the correct path. 
 If you don't know the correct path just keep it empty and then clean it and build.

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

I got this fixed by selecting the Tests target and searching for Bundle Loader in Build Settings and changing the product name in that path. I got this error because I have changed the Product name. The Bundle loader has the old product name in the path, so it searches for that path.

Comment: Your answer is right on, but the picture in the other answer grabbed my attention first :)

Answer (score 3):

Go to project name that given on top. Click on it. Go to "New Scheme" and change the Name to whatever you want.