# linker command failed with: ld: file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

> ld: file not found .../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Universal.app/Universal
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

Can you help with this error?

Comment: can u snap a cleared image plz ?

Comment: sure see the below link ,,, http://s16.postimg.org/ubx7030vp/Screen_Shot_2015_09_17_at_4_16_14_PM.png

Comment: Your problem is with the simulator 
Try these:
* rest ur simulator .
* use another one .
* quit simulator and rebuild .
* clean ur project.

Comment: unfortunately, not solved, I got the same issue

Comment: you got it corrected?

Comment: check this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280543/xcode-file-not-found-while-trying-to-run-app

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Try to hit <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> or select *Product -> Clean*.

Comment: this is not the case!

Answer (score 1):

I localize this error with simple mistake:

in my project i have 3 files: `main.m`, `SimpleClass.h`, `SimpleClass.m`;
[image: some project]

in file main, I have written:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SimpleClass.h"
#import "SimpleClass.m" //Mistake
```

When I erased the third line, all had built success.

Answer (score 0):

**Quit your Xcode** and restart again. It worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not a perfect solution, but part of solution I solved with the error code. Let me introduce my solutions. I hope this writing can be helpful to someone in my cases.

Shortly, There were 2 cases.

```
1. The function in code might not match with your action in your storyboard.
```

For example, using `control` + `drag`, you make an function of an action on the button. But with some reason, your function name or parameters could change. It makes disconnection between code and action. Then error can happens.

```
2. Your code nearby reference code could be entangled with sth...
(I don't know exactly why...)
```

In my case, when the code `NSString *mt = @"empty";` is embedded, the error occurs. The error isn't shown on xxx.m file, but on link message. So it's quite hard to find if you code down quickly.
(In addition, I wrote the same code, `NSString *mt = @"empty";`, in other source file, but that doesn't make any error...?)

Answer (score 0):

From the extremely long error message, Xcode is failing to link test files with the bundle. This issue occurs mainly in Xcode 7.

Try this:

> Just go to the project settings (click on the File Structure icon and then the app name, and then the Tests target), click Build Settings and then scroll down until you see Test Host (or type ‘host’ in the search box).
>
> Then clear the contents of both the Debug and Release hosts, circled below. The app should then compile without any issues.

[Source](http://www.robpercival.co.uk/upgrading-apps-to-xcode-7-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1/)